# Authorization Failed for Deployed Chatbot

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am having difficulty with a chatbot that I developed which works fine locally but after it was deployed to dev.botframework.com it does not appear to work.

My code is below and it breaks at the line...
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MyBot.AppServices.ServiceLUIS()); where it states 
{"Authorization for Microsoft App ID a8641a16-932c-49a5-af8b-a58ab2ce251f failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized'"}.

I have tried the instructions at [Troubleshooting Bot Framework Authentication](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/) with the following results:

- Step 1: Connect without password on localhost - Worked fine!
- Step 2: Verify AppID and Password are Correct - They are!
- Step 3: Enable security and run on localhost - This does not work :( However the endpoint is correct as are the MicrosoftAppID and Password
- Step 4: Connect to your bot using the Bot Framework Developer Portal - This also works!  However when using the web chat feature within the portal I also get an internal server error

Where it is breaking is on a call to my LUIS service so to me it seems like my Bot doesn't have authorization to call my LUIS model.  However I can't seem to find anything in Azure where my bot is published and LUIS Model resides where I would allow LUIS model to authorize access to my BOT.  Also don't see anything in Luis.ai or Bot Framework Portal.

Any ideas on how best to resolve would really be helpful!

```
namespace MyBot
{
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                **await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MyBot.AppServices.ServiceLUIS());**
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                var reply = HandleSystemMessage(activity);
                if (reply != null)
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you set the LUIS credentials in your LUIS Model?

Comment: @EzequielJadib - Thank you for your response.  Yes both the LUIS application ID and subscription keys are set.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Is the LUIS dialog decorated with the [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: @EzequielJadib Yes the Serializable attribute is in place in my LUIS dialog

Comment: Solved!  Ended up creating another new key and password for the bot and republishing and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Ended up creating another new key and password for the bot and republishing and it worked! –